# Call event at last slide - slid.bs.carousel

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I want the page should redirect to contact.php page once slider is finished (bs3)

I have created slider with 4 slides, once last slide will finish, page should redirect to contact.php

I tried $carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) { console.log('slide event!'); });

Comment: What are you asking and what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, i have tried few scripts, but no success, in bootsrap 3 carousel, when last slide will appear and finish, i want the page to redirect to contact.php

Comment: I tried $carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');
});

Comment: You should update your question to reflect this. More people may be willing to help you if you ask a clear question and show what work you've already done and why that work did not properly function.